# Asp.Net Missing IdentityModel.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019

I just installed the Visual studio 2019 version. My operating system is Windows 7. When I create an Asp.Net MVC project, files such as IdentityModel.cs are not created. When creating, I choose the individual accounts option for the authentication type. When I want to sign up to try it later, I get this error. Can you help me? Thank you.

**Error :**

A database operation failed while processing the request.
SqlException: Cannot open database "aspnet-examp-53313E8F-F6E8-4BFF-A962" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'merc'.

Applying existing migrations for ApplicationDbContext may resolve this issue
There are migrations for ApplicationDbContext that have not been applied to the database

When I try the Update-Database command, I get the ScriptHalted error.

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The error was coming from an older version of `PowerShell` that Windows 7 use. You need to update it and then add-migration and update database.

About this issue you can see this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/package-manager-console-scripthalted/753703).

The version of [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/install/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6) .